# Java IE8 plugin

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer-8, activex, ieaddon

I would like to develop a Java ActiveX plug-in for Internet Explorer 8.

The purpose of the application is to read data from the IE8 page which is currently open (in terms of JS, a few `getElementById`) and to form a mail message from it.

Everything is developed except one thing, which is more or less the initial thing:

- what exactly should be loaded when a button is clicked on IE8?
- The page from which I am going to read is dhtml, therefore JS getelementbyid does not work, I need it to read directly
- The URL of the page is also dynamic and external (i did not develop it): therefore is there even a possibility to get an element to java app straigt from the browser?

And probably at first I should ask if it is even possible to be done in Java, though I am sure it is possible with .net.

Any assistance/experience is welcome and much appreciated.

Comment: why only IE8 ? how about other versions of IE ?

Comment: The company currently relies on IE8 globally and the requirement is to make it work for IE8. Compatibility with 9 or 10 would be a great advantage considering future, but the initial requirement is having it work on ie8